# Windows Forms open and save default directories

Tags: c#, user-interface, winforms

I'm editing someone else's code that uses Windows Forms:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = LevelEditorConstants.PATH_TO_DATA_DIR;
```

Somehow, the directory that opens is totally different than the constant value that is assigned to it. How else can this value be set? A text search for a string that is part of the path that does open turns up nothing in my entire solution.

**UPDATE:** After attempting to save a file in the correct location (navigating there manually), and having it throw an exception for unrelated reasons, the problem is solved. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

SaveFileDialog and OpenFileDialog always uses last saved/opened folder. Had the same issue, not sure where it remembers/stores it, might be in the registry (like last opened documents in MS Word).

If you try it on a new session/user, it works fine.